# TCL/tk how to open folder

Tags: exec, tcl, tk-toolkit

I am trying to open a folder from tcl/tk using the below command

```
eval exec [auto_execok start] [list $folderpath]
```

it gives me error on syntax is incorrect.

in the tclsh command prompt when I tried 
`start $folderpath` the folder opens.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: it worked as below

eval exec [auto_execok start] {"$folderpath"}

thanks

Comment: I wonder if there's a FAQ somewhere on using `start` with `exec`? It's a continual source of trouble for newcomers to Tcl, and the problem is really due to the massive horrible-ness of `start`'s interface…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you were using is *almost* correct. You wanted this:

```
eval exec [auto_execok start] [list "" $folderpath]
```

That's because you needed that extra blank argument in there for `start` to consume (it's the “title” of the window to create, and is rather obscure if you're used to only feeding in relative filenames). This is a specific quirk of `start`, combined with how Tcl does the quoting of things being fed through the Windows process creation interface; what happens is that Tcl puts `"` chars round non-simple arguments (*almost* always the right thing to do) and that causes `start` to get confused and do the wrong thing, which leads to the error message. This is pretty horrible, but adding an extra empty argument defuses the problem.

You might also need to convert that path into the native format if it isn't already:

```
eval exec [auto_execok start] [list "" [file nativename $folderpath]]
```

(How do you know if it is native? Check if the directory separator is `/` — the Tcl standard, also native on Unix and OSX — or `\` — which Windows uses.)

In some cases, you may need `file attributes $folderpath -shortname` to work around problems. I hope you don't need that! (Hardly anything does these days, to be fair; it was only critical on pre-XP systems though it remains occasionally useful when dealing with very long paths.)

---

### Compatibility Forms

You are encouraged to use the syntactic changes proposed by Glenn if you're using Tcl 8.5 (or later), as they're clearer, easier to use, and marginally faster too (not that the last matters much here; the speed difference will be just noise compared to the cost of starting a subprocess):

```
exec {*}[auto_execok start] "" [file nativename $folderpath]
```

If you're using 8.4 (elderly, but supported) or before (why!?) then use the form with `eval` forms above.

Comment: I use 8.4 because they came with other tool(cadence) as inbuilt package.. Thanks,Nagaraj.

Comment: How about linux? above not working. output is "couldn't execute "/home/user/Desktop": permission denied"

Answer (score 1):

glenn's solution will not work for folders containing spaces.
My solution is:

```
set dir {C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office};# example
set escaped_dir [string map {\\ \\\\} [file nativename $dir]]
eval exec [auto_execok start] explorer $escaped_dir
```

But I want to know how to open the folder by default filer because I use an alternative filer.

Answer (score 0):

If you use tcl 8.5, you can write: `exec {*}[auto_execok start] $folderpath`

Comment: I am using 8.4. But eval exec [auto_execok start] {"$folderpath"} is what i need to open the folder location. I have a widget "open folder location" on clicking this button should open the destination folder in windows. They work good in Windows 7 but on windows-XP they hang. On investigation I found that the start.exe is not in the windows path where the exec actually searches.. struck how to deal with..any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks, Nagaraj